# Angular4: How to apply logic to input value?

Tags: angular, logic, interpolation

Taking a value from a form in app.component.html

```
  <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value" />
      <!-- <p><button (click)="submit()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Submit</button></p> -->
      <p>value: {{ value }}</p>
      <p>newvalue: {{ newvalue }}</p>
```

Then in app.component.ts I simply want to apply the logic of adding 2 to this value, passing it to newvalue and then use interpolation {{newvalue}} to display it in the app.component.html

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  value: number = null;
  newvalue: number = null;

  constructor(){
    // this.fun();
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    // this.fun();
  }

  // submit(){
  //   console.log(this.value);
  // }

  fun(){
    console.log('newvalue: ' + this.newvalue);
    console.log('value: ' + this.value);
    this.newvalue = this.value + 2;
    console.log('after->newvalue: ' + this.newvalue);
    console.log('after->value: ' + this.value);
  }
}
```

I have tried many things, but where should I place

```
this.newvalue = this.value + 2;
```

so that the value will update whenever the inout changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ngModelChange` event to accomplish this

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="fun()"/>
```

Comment: Ok I see, so I presume this means when the ngModel value changes call fun(). Thanks for your help, I'll try that now

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the value variable as below,

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value" />
<p>{{ value*2 }}</p>
```

or use the `ngModelChange`

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="fun()"/>
    <p>{{ newValue }}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Both answers are pretty much the same and I unfortunately can't mark both as the answer. But thank you for your really quick reply.